# Rails long chain model associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, rails-models

Well, I know how to handle associations from one model (call it ModelA) through the second one (ModelB) to the third one (ModelC).  But what if the third one(ModelC) is associated to the fith one(ModelE) trough the 4th (ModelD).

```
#ModelA 
has_many :model_bs
has_many :model_cs, :trough => :model_bs

#ModelC
has_many :model_ds
has_many :model_es, :trough => model_ds
```

The question is: how can I get the collection of ModelE records, associated with the specific ModelA record trough that chain?

Comment: I have tried the direct path a.model_cs.model_es, but it is not working aparently.

Comment: I have tried to write the query myself, but I am not very good at it and it looks too complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `model_cs` on an instance of `ModelA` will return an array of `model_cs`. If you then wanted to access all the `model_es` you would need to iterate over the array of `model_cs` and append those results to an array or hash.

```
array1 = @model_a.model_cs.all
array2 = []
array1.each do |x|
  array2 << x.model_es
end
```

`array2` now contains all the `model_es` whose ultimate parent is the original `model_a`.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of something similar, but thought there was something easyer.

Comment: You can shorten the code using `map`. The following (untested) should work `array = @model_a.model_cs.map{|x| x.model_es}`. This does the same thing but in a briefer form.

Comment: You can shorten it even further by using some syntactic sugar: `@model_a.model_cs.map(&:model_es)`. You may also want to call `flatten` and `uniq` on the result, depending on your requirements.